# How to load logistic regression model?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I want to train the logistic regression model using Apache Spark in Java. As first step I would like to train the model just once and save the model parameters (intercept and Coefficient). Subsequently use the saved model parameters to score at a later point in time. I am able to save the model in parquet file, using the following code

```
LogisticRegressionModel trainedLRModel = logReg.fit(data);
trainedLRModel.write().overwrite().save("mypath");
```

When I load the model to score, I get the following error.

```
LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression();
lr.load("//saved_model_path");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader.load(ReadWrite.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable$class.load(ReadWrite.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression$.load(LogisticRegression.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.load(LogisticRegression.scala)
```

Is there a way to train and save model and then evaluate(score) later? I am using Spark ML 2.1.0 in Java.

Answer (score 6):

I face the same problem with pyspark 2.1.1, when i change from LogisticRegression to LogisticRegressionModel , everything works well.

```
LogisticRegression.load("/model/path") # not works 

LogisticRegressionModel.load("/model/path") # works well
```

Comment: Had the same issue in `pyspark` with `StringIndexer` vs. `StringIndexerModel`

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Use [LogisticRegressionModel.load](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel$@load(path:String):org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel).

> **load(path: String): LogisticRegressionModel** Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of read.load(path).

---

As a matter of fact, as of Spark 2.0.0, the recommended approach to use Spark MLlib, incl. `LogisticRegression` estimator, is using the brand new and shiny [Pipeline API](http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#new-features-1).

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification._
val lr = new LogisticRegression()

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._
val tok = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("body")
val hashTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol(tok.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("features")

import org.apache.spark.ml._
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tok, hashTF, lr))

// training dataset
val emails = Seq(("hello world", 1)).toDF("body", "label")

val model = pipeline.fit(emails)

model.write.overwrite.save("mypath")
val loadedModel = PipelineModel.load("mypath")
```